# Chainlink api call to retrieve a string value from json (from a real-time API)

Tags: json, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, chainlink

I'd like to use Chainlink GET api to retreive the sensor value from a Real time sensor API. For example, the api might return an updated json file between a time interval. I'd like to know if there is any way, that Chainlink can use say getsensordata() to continiously keep requesting  for that particular sensor data in the json file, and return the value on chain. I've managed to request the sensor data from a json file, but it does require transaction for each request data. I've tried look into Upkeep , I'm not sure if we can use the getsensordata() inside CheckUpkeep ().

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning the entire JSON to your smart contract or just the value you need? the latter may be a better design strategy to avoid complex computations in your solidity smart contract.

Yes Chainlink automation can be used to get the data.  I'd recommend you use Chainlink Functions to make your get requests - its a faster and smoother workflow.

Check out the docs here: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions
You can also see the example of automation using chainlink functions here: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/tutorials/automate-functions/

Comment: Thanks, I only want to retrieve some value of the entire JSON file. The problem with my current method is that, I need to call the getsensordat() function and make transaction via metamask everytime I want the latest data from api. I just want to find a way to get the latest data from that json without human intervention .I also tried to look into whether we can autosign a transaction in a particular period of time but no luck yet.  I'll look into Chainlink Functions.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, there are two aspects to your requirement:

##### 1. Automation

If you want to automate the retrieval of your sensor data into your smart contract, you'll need to use something like Chainlink Automation, which allows you to automatically execute your smart contract's oracle request method every X seconds / minutes / etc. Alternatively, if you're technical, you can implement this by hand using a JS servlet, the web3.js library, and a reliable RPC connection (ie, Infura), to make your desired Web3 call (transaction) at X interval.

It's worth noting that either way, you'll need to pay the required fee for each transaction that it executes, as writing data on-chain can be expensive in terms of gas.

##### 2. Data retrieval

As far as retrieving your sensor (API) data on-chain, there are many Chainlink oracles willing to fulfill such a request. Many of these oracles (such as ourselves) host websites with easy code examples that you can simply drop into your smart contract to request your desired data from anywhere on the internet. As ZeusLawyer already mentioned, you can also use Chainlink Functions to program this request workflow manually.

Best of luck, and I hope that helps!